# Enable MultiDex in Unity Without using Gradle

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

I Use [External Dependency Manager for Unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) in my project. And I added my project dependencies in a .xml file instead of using Gradle. But now I got some error about MultiDex. Can I enable MultiDex in my project without using Gradle files?

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 75121 > 65536)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set minimum android API level to 21(Android 5.0 - Lollipop) and multidex will automatically be enabled. You can set it at player setting -> other settings.

[image]

Comment: So there is not anyway if I do not want to set the minimum Android API level to 21?

Comment: You can also enabled it by adding a line into your android manifest but can't remember it. Search it if you want but setting min api to 21 shouldn't hurt because it is already an old android version.